# How to distinguish between true and false with partitioningby?

Tags: java, java-stream

I am using java streams to separate the values "true" and "false" according to a certain condition, but they are all values counted as "false"
I have this code:

```
Map<String ,Map<Boolean,Long>> grouped= joinFirst.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t->t.get1().getLShipmode(),
                        partitioningBy(t-> t.get0().getOOrderpriority().equals("1-URGENT")  , counting())));

grouped.forEach((p, n) -> n.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.format("%s %s %d \n", p, k, v)));
```

And the result is this:

**MAIL       false 13209

MAIL       true 0

SHIP       false 13224

SHIP       true 0**

But it should be:

**MAIL       false 0 

MAIL       true 5376 

SHIP       false 0 

SHIP       true 5346**

Comment: What is the input?

Comment: With the question update, I doubt `MAIL false 13209
MAIL true 0` is not possible entries within a `Map`. Are you sure these are the data structures you are using as shared in the question?

Comment: What are `get0()` and `get1()`? Further, what is the result type and value of `getOOrderpriority()`? You can call `.equals("1-URGENT")` on *any* object, but it will only evaluate to `true` if you call it on an object that is 1) an instance of `String` and 2) precisely matching `"1-URGENT"`, case sensitive and including any white-space.

Answer (score 2):

You can repeat the pattern as:

```
grouped.forEach((p, n) -> n.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.format("%s %s %d", p, k, v)));
```

Comment: @joaoprog If you need your output on separate lines, please edit your original post with exactly what your required output should be.